# Enable and Disable other items in ng-repeat with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of user in my controller .

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('userList',function($scope){
  $scope.users = [
   {name:'A',family:'B'},
   {name:'C',family:'D'},
   {name:'E',family:'F'},
   {name:'G',family:'H'}
  ];
  $scope.enable = function($scope){
     //Do something
  };
});
```

and in my view i create a list with button for each user :

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="userList">
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="user in users">
      {{user.name + ' ' + user.family}} &nbsp; 
      <button type="button" ng-click="enable()"/>enable</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

and this is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cowed/5/edit?html,js,output) of sample. i want when user click on a enable button of one user this enable button change to disable and hide other users. and when click on disable button change a text to enable and show show the hide users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/biqizoca/1/edit), it just uses `ng-show` and `$scope` variables as flags.